# What does it mean that the differential operator is non-singular?

Tags: operator-theory

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $f : M \to M$ a $C^k$ diffeomorphism and $p$ a fixed point for $f$.

What does it mean that the differential $Df(p)$ is non-singular?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the linear map $Df(p) \colon T_pM \rightarrow T_pM$ is not singular (i.e invertible). In other words, $Df(p)$ is non-singular if $Df(p)v \neq 0$ for all $0 \neq v \in T_pM$.